# spring xml configuration in two separate xml files?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create a project with one spring configuration file. but inside the configuration file all beans are interfaces without any implementations. i would create one more project with all implementations. Also can i use abstract = true for all the beans(interfaces) of first project, so that user cannot use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a situation where you want to specify interfaces in the spring config file. So I think it is unnecessary for you as well. You can use `abstract=true` to create reusable or partial bean definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify interfaces in in your spring config, since they cannot be instantiated. What exactly are you trying to archive?

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question: Most ApplicationContext-Implementations have a String[] - Constructor where you can pass in more than one spring config file. You can also build an application context hierarchy by providing a parent application context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't i beans of interface types? but not concrete implementations? Thanks!

Comment: No, that simply would make no sense. What are you trying to do? By declaring the interface type in your consuming classes, you already decoupled your class from a concrete implementation. Abstract beans are not to be confused with abstract classes. An abstract bean can be used as a "template" where you set some common base properties, and then "derive" other bean definitions from it, where you can set the specific properties.